# Повторение одинаковых строк в C#

Tags: c#

При написании кода возник вопрос, возможно ли повторить в C# абсолютно одинаковые строки.

Конечно можно написать цикл, но строк всего 3 и вроде как код получится одинаковый по размеру. Может есть короткий и быстрый путь?

Чтобы быть немного конкретнее:

```
string x;
...
x = "blablabla..."+"blablabla..."+"blablabla...";
...
```

Можно ли записать короче?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуй, самым коротким однострочником будет этот:

```
string bla = "lorem ipsum ";
string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => bla));
```

Если вам часто приходится "умножать" строки, то можно сделать так:

```
static class StringExts
{
    public static string Times (this string @this, int times) => 
        string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, times).Select(i => @this));
}
```

И соответственно:

```
bla.Times(3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Чуть более короткий вариант:

```
string bla = "lorem ipsum ";
string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(bla, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

Самый короткий вариант все-таки такой:

```
string bla = "lorem ipsum ";
x = bla+bla+bla;
```

По крайней мере, для трех одинаковых строк - точно.

Comment: ну если так то Ваш вариант будет короче предыдущих даже для 10 одинаковых строк(ввиду отсутствия кода) :)

Comment: @Bald56rus, для 10 строк вариант @PashaPash все-таки будет короче моего. Хотя, если сократить переменную `bla` до одной буквы...

Comment: Это понятно, но вопрос больше для общего развития))) И вводить новую переменную не хотелось бы))) (почему новую, потому что в моем коде дальше переменная принимает разные значения и вариант со сложением не подходит) Но спасибо за подсказку. Просто думал есть какой-то простой синтаксис для умножения строк